# Cannot create $_SESSION in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

```
ID  UID         Username    Full Name       Password    Rank
0   131037146   DSaidov     Денис Саидов    PASS        Администратор
0   1970687978  LKatzarov   Любомир Кацаров PASS        Администратор
0   58367315    Admin       Георги Гергинов PASS        Собственик
```

This is my MySQL Table;
And I wanna create a $_SESSION that save the content of Full Name of the user that is currently logged in in the CMS.
Here is the auth.php file:

```
<?php
include("sql.php");
session_start();

function Destroy() {
    unset($_SESSION['UID']);
    unset($_SESSION['USERNAME']);
    unset($_SESSION['FULL NAME']);
    header("location: index-restricted.php");
}

if(isset($_SESSION['UID']) && isset($_SESSION['USERNAME'])) {
    $UID = $_SESSION['UID'];
    $username = $_SESSION['USERNAME'];
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `UID` = '$UID' AND `Username` = '$username'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($qry) != 1) { Destroy(); }
} else { Destroy(); }?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, why would `$_SESSION['UID']` and `$_SESSION['USERNAME']` be set to proceed with the MySQL query if you don't set them at any moment? Its a quite confusing stuff you're doing there.

Comment: Nowhere in the provided code are you even trying to set a session... What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I'm asking for a code that create session of the value Денис Саидов for example and when $_SESSION['USERNAME'] == DSaidov, and I type $_SESSION['Full Name'] to display Денис Саидов; If it can be done without SESSION, ok. I just want to know how to do it. :)